# Deducing a general rule for finding the formula of numerical series knowing the formula of the differences between two consecutive terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

The question appears to be generic so I'm trying to get into details . My younger brother had to solve this task : Suppose we are given the following numerical series, whose general formula we don't know.

7 , 20 , 57 , 166...

for n = 1,2,3...

Find the formula for the n-th term  of this series.

At first I tried to solve the problem choosing the path below but eventually I gave up trying and resorted to the practices of a charlatan mathematician by using a "try aimlessly and fail" method.
Let's take the difference between the n-th term and its predecessor so that  Δ = y(n) - y(n-1). We obtain the following series

13 , 37 , 109 ...

for n = 1,2,3...

Now a pattern becomes visible, so that if we subtract 1 to each of the terms we come up with the series 12,36,108 that can be generated by the formula 4 * 3^n .

Therefore the series of differences can be described by the formula 4* 3^n + 1 keeping in mind that n is a whole number .

I finally concluded that 3^n + n  yields the series BUT is there a way to deduce a general mathematically-rigorous rule for constructing the formula of the original series if we already know the formula of the series of its differences ? I am aware of the existence of discrete differential equations so I'm assuming that the response should lie in that particular field of mathematics . Thank you in advance .

Comment: Nor is it clear what the next few terms of the series is.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Did you mean $\color{red}2\times3^n+n$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes that's what I meant .  Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_n= 4\times3^n+1$ and $y_n=7+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1} x_n$,

then $y_n=7+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1}(4\times3^n+1) =7+4\times(3+3^2+\cdots+3^{N-1})+(N-1)$

$=7+4\times\dfrac{3^{N}-3}2+(N-1)=7+2\times3^{N}-6+N-1=2\times3^N+N.$

(Is that what you were asking for?)

Comment: Yes this was exactly what i was looking for ! Thank you very much though why does n range from  1 to N-1 ? Is it because for  N terms of the first series we can obtain N-1 terms for the second?

Comment: I indexed the series  $y_1=7, y_2=20, y_3=57,...$ and $x_1=13, x_2=37, x_3=109,...$ so $y_N=y_{N-1}+x_{N-1}$ for $N>1$ so $y_N-y_{N-1}=x_{N-1}$ so by telescoping $y_N-y_1=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1}x_n$ so $y_N=y_1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1}x_n$

Answer (score 0):

One approach is construct a difference table:

```
 7 20  57 166
13 37 109
24 72
48
```

If you take a leap of faith that it extends with multiples of 24 in the first column:

```
 7  20  57 166 467 1248
13  37 109 301 781
24  72 192 480
48 120 288
72 168
96
```

Now read off the first column as coefficients of $\binom{n}{k}$ to obtain
\begin{align}
&7\binom{n}{0}+13\binom{n}{1}+24\binom{n}{2}+48\binom{n}{3}+72\binom{n}{4}+\dots\\
&=7\binom{n}{0}+13\binom{n}{1}+24\sum_{k=2}^\infty (k-1)\binom{n}{k}\\
&=7+13n+24(n\cdot 2^{n-1}-2^n+1)\\
&=31+13n+24(n\cdot 2^{n-1}-2^n)
\end{align}
Finally, adjust $n\mapsto n-1$ because you started at $n=1$ instead of $n=0$:
$$31+13(n-1)+24((n-1) 2^{n-2}-2^{n-1})=18  + 13 n + 6(n-3)2^n$$
You can check that this formula yields your original sequence.